# automatic save before "Run in Terminal" in BBEdit

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line, text-editor

I am a new [BBEdit](http://barebones.com/products/bbedit/) user, with a long experience as [TextWrangler](http://barebones.com/products/textwrangler/) user.
In TextWrangler, I am used at running python scripts with the command "Run in Terminal", and in TextWrangler the default behaviour is to save the file before sending it to the terminal.

I noticed that in BBEdit, v11.1.2, if I give the "Run in Terminal" command for an unsaved file, the "autosave" option is not there, so I end up sending the "temporary file" for execution, which is in a temporary folder, and things "go wrong" (the script is in the wrong directory, and I need to access relative folders paths).

I looked in the preferences, but I didn't find yet where to set as default to save before running the file.

I have also searched with google, but to no avail.

Is it a "hidden" preference, to be given in the command line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have received the answer from BB's support:

> though there is no longer a GUI option in BBEdit to control this behavior, you can make BBEdit always save a script before running it by issuing the following Terminal command (which you can copy & paste):

```
defaults write com.barebones.bbedit RunScriptPrefs_SaveBeforeRunning -bool YES
```

I have also tested it, and it works!

Answer (score 1):

Contact Barebones, the developer's of BBEdit, about recreating this Text Wrangler behaviour in BBEdit.

[Barebone's support](http://barebones.com/contact/) is at support@barebones.com

They will be able to help.

### BBEdit 11 Release Notes

The [BBEdit 11 release notes](http://www.barebones.com/support/bbedit/arch_bbedit11.html) mention the following:

> The **#!** menu has been rearranged, and some behaviors for running #! scripts have been changed, as follows:
>
> - "Run…" has been changed to "Run with Options…". This brings up a dialog which lets you control what is done with the script output. The options to "Run in Debugger" and **"Run in Terminal" have been removed**, since you can do that explicitly from the #! menu itself (and scripts run that way don't get their output back into the application anyway).

Comment: Thank you @Graham Miln. Yes, I have sent a message to their support staff, and as soon as I receive a reply I will summarize it here.
About their release note, even "Run with Options…" doesn't address my "problem": as it is now, if I just hit command-S to "Save", before the command-R I have associated to "Run in Terminal", everything works fine. 
My goal is to save a keystroke, and have the "Save" automatically added before the "Run" command.